# How can you detect if current page is AMP?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, amp-html

I'm new to AMP and we only want something to happen if the current page is not an AMP page. Is there a universal property on `window` that we can see if it's defined in order to detect if the current view is AMP or not?

Some background: we're currently delivering a react app through a wordpress plugin and we're noticing some errors that might be from AMP pages only (even though we're not approved to run on AMP pages yet - not sure why our script is still attempting to load), so we'd like to not run our script if the current view is an AMP page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607406/how-to-check-amp-is-enabled-for-a-website-with-php

Answer (score 4):

I ended up seeing that the `<html>` tag tends to have an attribute `amp` when it's an AMP page. I'm not sure if it's always the case, but if anyone has the same question, this seems to work for my use-case:
 `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].hasAttribute('amp')`

Comment: Note that may fail with a javascript error if somehow the page does not have an `html` tag on it :)

Comment: @cale_b — The page **cannot** fail to have an HTML element in it. It doesn't matter if there is a tag for it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Not on`window`, but the AMP spec requires the `html` tag to have either the `⚡` or `amp` attribute, that is, either `<html ⚡>` or `<html amp>`. It also requires `<style amp-boilerplate>` inside `head`. Should be easy to use JavaScript to check.

For the spec statements, see https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/spec#required-markup

Answer (score 1):

There is the "AMP" property after the initialization of the AMP page. This test is more accurate than merely checking for the amp markup.

Beware that adding any custom javascript to do such detections will invalidate the AMP page. The page may still function on its own but will not be able to exploit the AMP-cache or search engine enhancements.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using chrome browser then install below extension:

AMP Validator(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amp-validator/nmoffdblmcmgeicmolmhobpoocbbmknc?hl=en)

If current page is using AMP then this extension become active in browser.